# Trying to display the max time record in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm currently building a Mysql db that handles the charging - discharging logs of a Lithium battery charger and I need to display from my Battery Cell Charge information the following

```
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     00:00:00    0.001   3.042   0   22.1`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     00:30:00    0.5     3.442   175.2   23.5`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     01:00:00    0.5     3.53    425.4   24.2`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     01:30:00    0.5     3.627   675.5   24.7`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     02:00:00    0.5     3.683   925.7   24.7`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     02:30:00    0.5     3.757   1175.8  25`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     03:00:00    0.5     3.851   1426    25.2`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     03:30:00    0.5     3.939   1676.1  25`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     04:00:00    0.5     4.02    1926.3  25.2`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     04:30:00    0.5     4.107   2176.5  24.7`
`1B     LG HG2 18650    103     05:00:00    0.5     4.147   2426.6  24.7`
```

(Specific Data on a 30 minute interval until the 5 hours mark)
Now I want to incorporate the last log entry of the charge cycle. I added another or clause in my where and selected the max Time

```
    SELECT 
    `Cell`, 
    `Cell_Make_Model` as `CEll Make And Model`, 
    `Charge_number` as `Charge Number`, 
    `Time_in_charge` as `Charge Clock`, 
    `Current` as `Charge Current`, 
    `Voltage` as `Cell Voltage`, 
    `Capacity` as `Charging Capacity`, 
    `Cell_Temp` as `Cell Temperature (In Celsius)` 
FROM 
    `Cell_Charge_Info` as a 
    INNER JOIN Cell_Make_And_Model b on a.cell = b.Cell_Code 
WHERE 
    b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 0 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 1800 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 3600 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 5400 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 7200 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 9000 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 10800 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 12600 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 14400 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 16200 
    or b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`)= 18000 
    or a.Time_in_charge = (
        select 
            max(c.Time_in_charge)
        from 
            Cell_Charge_Info as c 
        where 
            c.cell = a.cell 
            and c.Charge_number = a.Charge_number
            and c.time_in_charge=max(a.time_in_Charge))
```

When I execute it in phpMyAdmin the system hangs and I get a 100% CPU Utilization from mysqld process.
If I remove the last or-select from the query it's fully functional but the result-set does not contain the last log entry of the charge.
Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to put parenthesis around your and/or's to show which should be grouped. Otherwise mysql will get really confused and could match all the rows. `where (this and that) or (other and another)` or `where this and (that or another) and (other and thisotherthing)`

Comment: It seems like no matter what, `Cell_Make_Model` is the same, so don't make 10 filters that does the same thing. Use > `b.Cell_Make_Model = '...' AND time_to_sec(..) IN(1800,3600,5400....)` . This will save a lot of unnecessary `OR` . In addition, use parenthesis while using `OR` !!!

Comment: How is `TIME_TO_SEC(Time_in_charge)= 0 ` different from `Time_in_charge= 0`?

Comment: Have you not just made `WHERE b.Cell_Make_Model = "LG HG2 18650" ORDER BY Time_in_charge` immensly complex for no reason

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: on the first part of your answer you are absolutely right and I've tweaked my code, on the second part I've used to calculate everything in seconds so it's a personal preference, on the third part the charger produces 1 record per second so I need to display only 11 records out of 30000+

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem - but it's surely easier to read...

```
SELECT Cell
     , Cell_Make_Model  `Cell Make And Model`
     , Charge_number    `Charge Number`
     , Time_in_charge   `Charge Clock`
     , Current          `Charge Current`
     , Voltage          `Cell Voltage`
     , Capacity         `Charging Capacity`
     , Cell_Temp        `Cell Temperature (In Celsius)`
  FROM Cell_Charge_Info a 
  JOIN Cell_Make_And_Model b 
    ON b.Cell_Code = a.cell 
 WHERE (b.Cell_Make_Model = "LG HG2 18650" AND TIME_TO_SEC(Time_in_charge) IN(0,1800,3600,5400,7200,9000,10800,12600,14400,16200,18000)) 
    OR a.Time_in_charge = (SELECT MAX(c.Time_in_charge)
                             FROM Cell_Charge_Info c      
                            WHERE c.cell = a.cell 
                              AND c.Charge_number = a.Charge_number
                              AND c.time_in_charge = MAX(a.time_in_Charge)
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem through a view that holds the last log of each charge and a union all query.

```
SELECT 
    `Cell`, 
    `Cell_Make_Model` as `CEll Make And Model`, 
    `Charge_number` as `Charge Number`, 
    `Time_in_charge` as `Charge Clock`, 
    `Current` as `Charge Current`, 
    `Voltage` as `Cell Voltage`, 
    `Capacity` as `Charging Capacity`, 
    `Cell_Temp` as `Cell Temperature (In Celsius)` 
FROM 
    `Cell_Charge_Info` as a 
    INNER JOIN Cell_Make_And_Model b on a.cell = b.Cell_Code 
WHERE 
    b.Cell_Make_Model like "LG HG2 18650" 
    AND time_to_sec(`Time_in_charge`) in (
        0, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 
        12600, 14400, 16200, 18000
    ) 
Union ALL 
Select 
    `Cell`, 
    `CEll Make And Model`, 
    `Charge Number`, 
    `Charge Clock`, 
    `Charge Current`, 
    `Cell Voltage`, 
    `Charging Capacity`, 
    `Cell Temperature (In Celsius)` 
from 
    LG_HG2_Charge_Log_MaxTime
order by `Cell`,`Charge Number`,`Charge Clock`
```

Thank you for the pointers that made my code A LOT Cleaner!